# What is a proper way of defining side effects in action(not async thunks) when using redux toolkit?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, redux-toolkit

Currently I'm digging into Redux Toolkit with Typescript and I'm stuck with a logout action. It basically shoudn't have any payload at all, but should modify localStorage and axios config.
I'm aware of two ways that work slightly different.

One is to define reducer with a `prepare` callback inside of a `createSlice`:

```
const authSlice = createSlice({
  name: "authentication",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    logout: {
      reducer: () => initialState,
      prepare: () => {
        api.logout();
        return { payload: undefined, error: undefined, meta: undefined };
      },
    },
  },...
```

In this case type signature of the prepare callback forces me to explicitly return a `payload`, `error` and `meta` properties.

Another way is to use a `createAction` with a `prepare` callback:

```
export const logout = createAction("authentication/logout", () => {
  api.logout();
  return { payload: undefined };
});
```

This is a bit better looking solution. At least I don't have to pass an `error` and `meta`. But still forced to return `payload` even though its not needed.

A bit confused why `prepare` function signatures differs, but thats not the point.

My question is how you would handle such cases. Maybe I'm doing something completelly wrong?

I understand that there is also option to use middleware, but setting up middleware that handles only one action looks like an overhead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are confusing terms a bit here - and missing one important term ;)

An *action* is an object with a `type` property. You can never execute code there.

An *action creator* is a function that returns an *action*. You could execute code here, but it will be executed before dispatching the resulting action.

An *async thunk* is a special form of *thunk* that attaches lifecycle actions (pending/fulfilled/rejected) to a *thunk*. To be exact, the `createAsyncThunk` function creates an *async thunk action creator* - a function that creates something you can *dispatch* for it to be triggered.

So, the thing that is missing: What is a *thunk*?

A thunk is a function that is dispatched - and then executed by the *redux-thunk* middleware. That function will be passed `dispatch` as first argument and `getState` as the second argument so you can trigger more redux-related stuff from in there if necessary.

So you are looking for a thunk. Commonly, those are written with an action creator, so you are looking for a *thunk action creator*.

```js
const logout = (potentiallySomeArgument) => (dispatch, getState) => {
  api.logout(potentiallySomeArgument);
  // maybe you also want to dispatch an action to clear state
  dispatch(userSlice.clear())
}
```

This would be dispatchged like any other action, so the fuctionality is completely irrelevant to your component:

```js
dispatch(logout("whatever"))
```

Comment: You are absolutely right, I've completely forgotten about such entity as thunk and what it really is despite I'm using async thunks. Have to catch up with this. Many thanks. Unintetionaly messed up with terms, I understand that action is just an object and obviously can't contain any logic. So as I uderstand `prepare` callback is for modifying action object only, and should not contain any side effects? There are not much information in the docs about this. Also maybe you are aware of diferent type signatures for  `prepare` notations in `createSlice` and `createAction`.

Comment: What "different type signatures" are you referring to?

Comment: prepare is for "preparing" the action. You can add side effects but it would be like side effects in an action creator. I would advise against it, asides from side effects like "creating a random id"

Comment: @phry does it mean any non-async / api-based side effect have to go on a `thunk` defined outside `createSlice`? I'm wondering if anything change in RTK since your answer. I guess it still applies because `extraReducers` doesn't let you call actions of the same slice.

Comment: @Mikel Yes. Although you can also use RTK Query for API requests. Generally, I would recommend just following the official Redux Tutorial. That is up to date and will teach you multiple ways of doing this. https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts

Answer (score 0):

I'd willing to bet that `api.logout` is async function.

If it is `async`, you should use [createAsyncThunk](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk) instead of `createAction`

Please see example:

```js
import { createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

const api = async () => { }

const increment = createAsyncThunk('counter/increment', api)

const action = increment() // AsyncThunkAction<void, void, {}>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgYygUwIYzQQQM4CeAdsgCoAWArkQNZwC%20cAZlBCHAOQAC6AJpQA8AVngD0MCBAA2NYDA4BYAFDLkEInngYwwOAF44GQiTgAKAJT6AfIgbLV6zXGAl0INEXgHUmbPmJkVLSmHGrU2FCiLj7unhwANIY65vZKahpayDDA6vrOrmixMBZwoqJw-iQU1DQ4WTlEADwAbhDAvImt7YkI9FbKQA)

Comment: Login and register actions are async thunks, no problem with this, but not logout. As I've mentioned it manipulates a localStorage and inmemory config object. All operations are syncronous.